# Where are the comments?

Tags: support, comments

On my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397400/make-classes-final-by-default-in-eclipse/6397450#6397450). I have 19 comments on it but now I can see only 1 comment which is latest. Why? Where are the other comments?

New comment notification box screen shot:-

[image]

My answer:-

[image]

Comment: It must have been cleaned out for having so many comments.  Must have been some unrelated discussion going on and a mod cleaned out the noise or something.

Comment: @JeffMercado, how about adding that as an actual answer rather than just a comment? (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were deleted either by the person who commented, or by a moderator. Deleted activity is sometimes reflected in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™, as items in that list are cached and may not be updated for a while.

Comment: Most likely moderator, after someone flagged one of the comments.